# Text overlay on video ESP32

Tags: arduino, video-streaming, overlay, framebuffer, esp32

I've started playing around with an ESP32-CAM.
The demo Arduino camserver scripts work quite well with the face recognition etc. but now I'm trying to implement something useful.

I know that the example at [here](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/tree/master/libraries/ESP32/examples/Camera/CameraWebServer) manages to somehow do overlay text onto the video feed during facial recognition but I cannot figure out how to implement this feature onto a much simpler streaming code like [this](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-cam-video-streaming-web-server-camera-home-assistant/).

How would I do a text overlay with this example?

```
    /*********
  Rui Santos
  Complete project details at https://RandomNerdTutorials.com

  IMPORTANT!!! 
   - Select Board "ESP32 Wrover Module"
   - Select the Partion Scheme "Huge APP (3MB No OTA)
   - GPIO 0 must be connected to GND to upload a sketch
   - After connecting GPIO 0 to GND, press the ESP32-CAM on-board RESET button to put your board in flashing mode

  Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
  of this software and associated documentation files.

  The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
  copies or substantial portions of the Software.
*********/

#include "esp_camera.h"
#include <WiFi.h>
#include "esp_timer.h"
#include "img_converters.h"
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "fb_gfx.h"
#include "soc/soc.h" //disable brownout problems
#include "soc/rtc_cntl_reg.h"  //disable brownout problems
#include "dl_lib.h"
#include "esp_http_server.h"

//Replace with your network credentials
const char* ssid = "REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_SSID";
const char* password = "REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_PASSWORD";

#define PART_BOUNDARY "123456789000000000000987654321"

// This project was only tested with the AI Thinker Model
#define CAMERA_MODEL_AI_THINKER

// Not tested with these boards
//#define CAMERA_MODEL_M5STACK_PSRAM
//#define CAMERA_MODEL_WROVER_KIT

#if defined(CAMERA_MODEL_WROVER_KIT)
  #define PWDN_GPIO_NUM    -1
  #define RESET_GPIO_NUM   -1
  #define XCLK_GPIO_NUM    21
  #define SIOD_GPIO_NUM    26
  #define SIOC_GPIO_NUM    27  
  #define Y9_GPIO_NUM      35
  #define Y8_GPIO_NUM      34
  #define Y7_GPIO_NUM      39
  #define Y6_GPIO_NUM      36
  #define Y5_GPIO_NUM      19
  #define Y4_GPIO_NUM      18
  #define Y3_GPIO_NUM       5
  #define Y2_GPIO_NUM       4
  #define VSYNC_GPIO_NUM   25
  #define HREF_GPIO_NUM    23
  #define PCLK_GPIO_NUM    22

#elif defined(CAMERA_MODEL_M5STACK_PSRAM)
  #define PWDN_GPIO_NUM     -1
  #define RESET_GPIO_NUM    15
  #define XCLK_GPIO_NUM     27
  #define SIOD_GPIO_NUM     25
  #define SIOC_GPIO_NUM     23 
  #define Y9_GPIO_NUM       19
  #define Y8_GPIO_NUM       36
  #define Y7_GPIO_NUM       18
  #define Y6_GPIO_NUM       39
  #define Y5_GPIO_NUM        5
  #define Y4_GPIO_NUM       34
  #define Y3_GPIO_NUM       35
  #define Y2_GPIO_NUM       32
  #define VSYNC_GPIO_NUM    22
  #define HREF_GPIO_NUM     26
  #define PCLK_GPIO_NUM     21

#elif defined(CAMERA_MODEL_AI_THINKER)
  #define PWDN_GPIO_NUM     32
  #define RESET_GPIO_NUM    -1
  #define XCLK_GPIO_NUM      0
  #define SIOD_GPIO_NUM     26
  #define SIOC_GPIO_NUM     27
  #define Y9_GPIO_NUM       35
  #define Y8_GPIO_NUM       34
  #define Y7_GPIO_NUM       39
  #define Y6_GPIO_NUM       36
  #define Y5_GPIO_NUM       21
  #define Y4_GPIO_NUM       19
  #define Y3_GPIO_NUM       18
  #define Y2_GPIO_NUM        5
  #define VSYNC_GPIO_NUM    25
  #define HREF_GPIO_NUM     23
  #define PCLK_GPIO_NUM     22
#else
  #error "Camera model not selected"
#endif

static const char* _STREAM_CONTENT_TYPE = "multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=" PART_BOUNDARY;
static const char* _STREAM_BOUNDARY = "\r\n--" PART_BOUNDARY "\r\n";
static const char* _STREAM_PART = "Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\nContent-Length: %u\r\n\r\n";

httpd_handle_t stream_httpd = NULL;

static esp_err_t stream_handler(httpd_req_t *req){
  camera_fb_t * fb = NULL;
  esp_err_t res = ESP_OK;
  size_t _jpg_buf_len = 0;
  uint8_t * _jpg_buf = NULL;
  char * part_buf[64];

  res = httpd_resp_set_type(req, _STREAM_CONTENT_TYPE);
  if(res != ESP_OK){
    return res;
  }

  while(true){
    fb = esp_camera_fb_get();
    if (!fb) {
      Serial.println("Camera capture failed");
      res = ESP_FAIL;
    } else {
      if(fb->width > 400){
        if(fb->format != PIXFORMAT_JPEG){
          bool jpeg_converted = frame2jpg(fb, 80, &_jpg_buf, &_jpg_buf_len);
          esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
          fb = NULL;
          if(!jpeg_converted){
            Serial.println("JPEG compression failed");
            res = ESP_FAIL;
          }
        } else {
          _jpg_buf_len = fb->len;
          _jpg_buf = fb->buf;
        }
      }
    }
    if(res == ESP_OK){
      size_t hlen = snprintf((char *)part_buf, 64, _STREAM_PART, _jpg_buf_len);
      res = httpd_resp_send_chunk(req, (const char *)part_buf, hlen);
    }
    if(res == ESP_OK){
      res = httpd_resp_send_chunk(req, (const char *)_jpg_buf, _jpg_buf_len);
    }
    if(res == ESP_OK){
      res = httpd_resp_send_chunk(req, _STREAM_BOUNDARY, strlen(_STREAM_BOUNDARY));
    }
    if(fb){
      esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
      fb = NULL;
      _jpg_buf = NULL;
    } else if(_jpg_buf){
      free(_jpg_buf);
      _jpg_buf = NULL;
    }
    if(res != ESP_OK){
      break;
    }
    //Serial.printf("MJPG: %uB\n",(uint32_t)(_jpg_buf_len));
  }
  return res;
}

void startCameraServer(){
  httpd_config_t config = HTTPD_DEFAULT_CONFIG();
  config.server_port = 80;

  httpd_uri_t index_uri = {
    .uri       = "/",
    .method    = HTTP_GET,
    .handler   = stream_handler,
    .user_ctx  = NULL
  };

  //Serial.printf("Starting web server on port: '%d'\n", config.server_port);
  if (httpd_start(&stream_httpd, &config) == ESP_OK) {
    httpd_register_uri_handler(stream_httpd, &index_uri);
  }
}

void setup() {
  WRITE_PERI_REG(RTC_CNTL_BROWN_OUT_REG, 0); //disable brownout detector

  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.setDebugOutput(false);

  camera_config_t config;
  config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
  config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0;
  config.pin_d0 = Y2_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d1 = Y3_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d2 = Y4_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d3 = Y5_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d4 = Y6_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d5 = Y7_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d6 = Y8_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d7 = Y9_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_xclk = XCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pclk = PCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_vsync = VSYNC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_href = HREF_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_sda = SIOD_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_scl = SIOC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pwdn = PWDN_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_reset = RESET_GPIO_NUM;
  config.xclk_freq_hz = 20000000;
  config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_JPEG; 
  config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_UXGA;
  config.jpeg_quality = 10;
  config.fb_count = 2;

  // Camera init
  esp_err_t err = esp_camera_init(&config);
  if (err != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.printf("Camera init failed with error 0x%x", err);
    return;
  }
  // Wi-Fi connection
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");

  // Start streaming web server
  startCameraServer();
  Serial.print("Camera Stream Ready! Go to: http://");
  Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
}

void loop() {
  delay(1);
}
```

Comment: I have been looking for days how to overlay text on an image and cannot find solutions. I have just found the following websites, hopefully the answer will be in there. https://www.esp32.com/viewforum.php?f=23 and https://www.espressif.com/en/developer-zone

Answer (score 5):

I know it is maybe late, but you can easily print text over the image.

The typical procedure will be as follows:

1- get the image from the camera:

```
camera_fb_t *fb = esp_camera_fb_get();
```

2- get the image matrix:

```
dl_matrix3du_t *image_matrix = dl_matrix3du_alloc(1, fb->width, fb->height, 3);
```

3- Change the format of the image stored in the image_matrix:

```
fmt2rgb888(fb->buf, fb->len, fb->format, image_matrix->item);
```

4- print the text of your choice over that matrix (FF is red color, you can use any uint32_t. Also, take a look at the rgb_print function posted in @sashok1337 response; you can modify it to send the position of the string):

```
rgb_print(image_matrix, 0x000000FF, "test");
```

4- Define a buffer and convert the martrix to jpg(you can play with the settings here):

```
size_t _jpg_buf_len = 0;
uint8_t * _jpg_buf = NULL;
bool jpeg_converted = fmt2jpg(image_matrix->item, fb->width*fb->height*3, fb->width, fb->height, PIXFORMAT_RGB888, 90, &_jpg_buf, &_jpg_buf_len);
```

Once you finished working with the image_matrix, remember to free the memory used by the dl_matrix3du_alloc in the second point above (thank you, @fuenfundachtzig):

```
dl_matrix3du_free(image_matrix);
```

The "frame" with the text over it will be stored in the _jpg_buf array, you can transmit or store it whenever you want.

Comment: Don't forget to release the memory allocated by `dl_matrix3du_alloc`.

Answer (score 2):

You can look to CameraWebServer example, specifically to file app_httpd.cpp . I didn't test code below, but I just want to show the idea. Read whole stream_handler function from example and everything will be clear.

You should change

```
bool jpeg_converted = frame2jpg(fb, 80, &_jpg_buf, &_jpg_buf_len);
```

to

```
dl_matrix3du_t *image_matrix = dl_matrix3du_alloc(1, fb->width, fb->height, 3);
fmt2rgb888(fb->buf, fb->len, fb->format, image_matrix->item);

// HERE print some text
rgb_print(image_matrix, 0x000000FF, "Hello!");

bool jpeg_converted = fmt2jpg(image_matrix->item, fb->width*fb->height*3, fb->width, fb->height, PIXFORMAT_RGB888, 90, &_jpg_buf, &_jpg_buf_len);

dl_matrix3du_free(image_matrix);
```

And the print function (also from app_httpd.cpp file)

```
static void rgb_print(dl_matrix3du_t *image_matrix, uint32_t color, const char * str){
               fb_data_t fb;
               fb.width = image_matrix->w;
               fb.height = image_matrix->h;
               fb.data = image_matrix->item;
               fb.bytes_per_pixel = 3;
               fb.format = FB_BGR888;
               fb_gfx_print(&fb, (fb.width - (strlen(str) * 14)) / 2, 10, color, str);
}
```